# Android 9patch opaque corners

Tags: android-layout, android-notifications, nine-patch

I show notifications using android 9patch image:

[image]

I tried to use white and transparent background, but it's still opaque. And yes, the name of file ends with `.9.png`

Here is the layout of notification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/message"
                android:layout_width="300dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/common_whitespace"
                android:textColor="@color/screen_game_dialog_text_color"
                android:textSize="14dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/notification_popup_default"
                android:contentDescription="@null"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is 9patch image (it's not mine, so I've added a sort of watermark):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you referring to the paper/wood effect image and not the light blue round rectangle? Can you attach your 9 patch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background of corners is white, alpha value is not 0. Background has to be completely transparent.